# Use of bitfields for arm64 architecture

Tags: c++, cuda, arm64, nvcc

I have a code base with following data structure.

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct points_t {
   uint16_t r, r2;
   uint16_t intensity : 12;
   uint16_t intensity2 : 12;
   uint8_t match, match2, retro;
   uint16_t noise_floor :12;
   uint16_t fr_retro1 :1;
   uint16_t fr_retro2 :1;
   uint16_t sr_retro1 :1;
   uint16_t sr_retro2 :1;
};
struct header_common_t{
   int16_t elevation, azimuth;
   uint16_t omit : 1;
   uint16_t c1p1 : 1;
   uint16_t c1p2 : 1;
   uint16_t retro : 1;
   uint16_t rsvd : 12;
};
typedef struct header_16_t {
   header_common_t hdr; 
   points_t points[16];
} hdr_16_t;

typedef struct header_8_t {   //main.h(74) line
   header_common_t hdr; 
   points_t points[8];
} hdr_8_t;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Upon trying to compile the code for `aarch64` (or arm64), I get the following error:

```
main.h(74): error: "Bitfields and field types containing bitfields are not supported in packed structures and unions for device compilation!"
```

I understand that it is due to the use of bitfields in the above structs. Why does the compiler issue error only for `header_8_t` and not for `header_16_t`? How to fix this bitfield issue?

Comment: Bitfields are just a nightmare to handle. For one thing the order of the fields can be changed for bits in a single unit, compiler might not allow packed bitfield structures, and other small corner cases that are not well-defined enough. More often than not it's easier to handle it  explicitly with a long integer and bit operations (masking, shifting, etc.).

Comment: From [Bit-field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field#Notes): "_...The following properties of bit-fields are implementation-defined:... Everything about the actual allocation details of bit-fields within the class object..."_  So you would need to inspect the structure layout by hand to ensure the layout is what you expect.

Comment: I see three uses of bit-fields: pack structures in memory to be memory efficient, target specific bit-fields on a specific platform, and create a portable storage efficient data-type. It seems this is the latter case, where bit-fields are really problematic. However contrary to the anti-bit-field propaganda, it still works for the other two cases (and as Richard Crittern says look at the result for 2nd case).

Comment: Bit field packing and unpacking is usually better using the Boolean arithmetic operators than relying on a bitfield.  Remember to using unsigned integral quantities when playing with bits (e.g. `uint8_t`, `uint32_t`, etc.)